# question about matrices, first and second fundamental forms

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, linear-transformations, determinant

Consider a regular surface $M=(a(x_1,x_2),b(x_1,x_2),c(x_1,x_2)) $. The matrix of the I Fundamental Form is given by $g_{i,j}= \langle M_i, M_j\rangle $, where $M_i$ is the tangent vector $\frac{\partial M}{\partial x_i}$. The matrix coefficients for the II Fundamental Form are given by $h_{ij}=-\langle N, x_{ij}\rangle$, here $N$ is the normal vector. Consider the diagonal matrix with $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ in the diagonal.

I have the following expression

$$[M_1,M_2]^T[\lambda][M_1,M_2] - \gamma h_{i,j}$$

and I would like to know for each $\gamma$ and $\lambda$'s the above matrix has a zero determinant, or equivalent when its rank in less than 2.

I noticed that $[M_1, M_2]^T [M_1,M_2]$ is precisely the matrix of the I Fundamental Form, but this didn't help me a lot.

Comment: Go back to square one. First, there are only two $\lambda$s. Second, you need a matrix on the right-hand side. You are looking for the eigenvalues of $\mathrm I ^{-1}\mathrm{II}$.

Comment: What I meant by  $[M_1,M_2]$ is the matrix formed by the tangent vectors in the lines. So $[M_1,M_2]$ is a $2\times3$ matrix and $[\lambda]$ is a $3x3$, so the multiplication $[M_1,M_2] [\lambda][M_1,M_2]^T$ makes sense, and gives us a 2x2 matrix. I think that the expression on the question does not give me the eigenvalues of the shape operator, as you saying. Anyway, I can be wrong too.

Comment: This is a mess. The $h_{ij}$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix. I would suggest working with $M$ as a column vector, not row.

Comment: Yes, we have two 2x2 matrices, but one comes from the multiplication of the $2x3 $, $3 \times 3$ and $3 \times 2$ matrices. I don't think it's a mess, it might have nothing to do with the shape operator matrix, which is why I need help.

Comment: As you’ve set it up, isn’t the left-hand side $3\times 3$?

Comment: From your final line in the post, you are doing what I said and using columns, and end up with a $2\times 2$, so, yes, you need three $\lambda$s. I have no idea what this is. The classic thing is to look at solutions of $\det(\mathbf{II}-\lambda\mathbf I)=0$.